# How can I change the size of an array from user argument?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, command-line-arguments, producer-consumer

I want to be able to pass the structure holding the buffer array onto the threads so they can all alter the array and use it as a shared buffer array. So I created a pointer buff in the structure and dynamic allocated in the main passing the size of the buffer to the struct which doesn't make sense to me to set the size of the array to a malloc area since it's not a fixed size it's just allocated memory. So I guess I shouldn't even be using malloc right? Only reason I thought I should use it because my buffer size isn't set at compile time but during runtime as a command line argument. I would rather not use a dynamic array because in my producer consumer program I need to have them know the end of the array size so it needs to be fixed array size provided from user input. Do I have to use a dynamic array since the size of the array is given as a command line argument? Also another question I had was, want's the point of setting your buffer array in global memory. I see a lot of people doing that for their producer consumer solutions but it confuses me because isn't all the memory from the parent shared among the threads so they wouldn't have to put it in global memory.

Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>


//function declarations
void* producer(void*);
void* consumer(void*);

typedef struct {
    sem_t mtx;
    sem_t empty;
    sem_t full;
    int *buff;
    int buffSize;
    int psTime;
    int csTime;

} shared_info;



int main (int argc, char*argv[]) {
     shared_info *shr;
    //initializing threads
    pthread_t pro, con;
    
    if( argc != 4 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "incorrect amount of arguments\n"); //It prints an error message (to stderr) when it's the incorrect number of arguments.
        exit(1);
    } 
   
 
    //grabbing input from command line arguments
    shr->buffSize = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    shr->psTime = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
    shr->csTime = strtol(argv[3], NULL, 10);

    shr->buff = malloc(shr->buffSize * sizeof(int)); // alocates memory based on command line Argument
    if (shr->buff == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    shr->buff[shr->buffSize]; // creates an array of buffSize pointed to by buff in Struct.
    


    if (buff == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }
   
    printf("buff: %d psTime:%d csTime: %d", buffSize,shr->psTime,shr->csTime);

    sem_init(&shr->mtx, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&shr->full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&shr->empty, 0, buffSize);

    pthread_create(&pro, NULL, producer, shr);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_create(&con, NULL, consumer, shr);

    pthread_join(pro, NULL);
    pthread_join(con, NULL);

    printf("Main thread done.\n");
    sem_destroy(&shr->mtx);
    sem_destroy(&shr->empty);
    sem_destroy(&shr->full);

    return 0;
}

//producer thread 
void *producer(void * arg){
    int i;
    while( true){
     
        sem_wait(&shr->empty);
        sem_wait(&shr->mtx);
        //produces" random integers between 1000-900
        int rand1 = rand()%101+900;
        printf("%d\n", rand1);
  }
  
}

//Consumer thread
void *consumer(void * arg){
 
}
```

Comment: Didn't go through the full code, but reading the question I see two options: 1. Indeed live without `malloc`; provide a sufficiently large statically (or possibly locally) allocated buffer – its size imposing the absolute maximum of entries usable. If someone needs more of – bad luck… 2. *Do* use `malloc`; if possible, wait with calling until size is known – if not possible, then `malloc` some appropriate default and if needing more, [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)! Pay attention on doing it correctly – not losing reference to old buffer if re-allocation fails!

Comment: Re-allocating correctly (you need to add the buffer size to the struct – or alternative means to determine current size!): `size_t newSize = shr->buffSize * 2; int* tmp = realloc(shr->buff, newSize); if(tmp) { /* successful! */ shr->buff = tmp; shr->buffSize = newSize; } else { /* whatever appropriate error handling */ }` – alternatively to duplicating size you might e.g. add fix chunks or otherwise increase size in whatever appropriate way. Important is that you only update the buffer variable if you assured a new buffer is available, otherwise the old one is lost (-> memory leak).

Comment: why are you multiplying buffsize by 2?

Comment: It's just one of the standard ways to get more memory. Intention usually is to limit number of re-allocations (they can be rather expensive). If you duplicate size then the reserve of entries increases with every re-allocation occurring – with the expectation that next re-allocation then occurs much later than current one. As mentioned already, there are alternatives ;)

Comment: If you think, doubling the buffer size in each step will consume too much memory in the end, you can add a final call to `realloc` after you have added every element to the buffer and reduce to the size you actually need.

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't get why I have to use Realloc.. i'm only going to allocate memory once based off the user argument for the size of the array. The size of the array isn't going to change after that.

Comment: @Aconcagua  I don't get why I have to use Realloc.. i'm only going to allocate memory once based off the user argument for the size of the array. The size of the array isn't going to change after that.

Comment: @JosueNunez Well, you'd use `realloc` in case you *cannot* wait until size from user is known – or if user might request more memory later on – *if* size won't change *and* you can wait until you receive user input *then* one single call to `malloc` is fine, then you can forget about all this `realloc` stuff. Your question just wasn't fully clear about, thus I provided both variants (note: *'if possible – if not possible'*).

Comment: Side note: Your code creates two threads and then simply waits for them terminating – thus the main thread, that *still* exists – just sleeps for the rest of the time. You can spare quite some resources (threads aren't that cheap) if you re-use the main thread for running one of the necessary tasks itself: `pthread_create(..., producer, ...); consumer(shr); pthread_join(pro, NULL); /* skipping the second join, of course */`.

Comment: @Aconcagua Also where would I put my array buff[]? Wouldn't it need to be in global struct for the thread to be able to add data into it... Like for example the user inputs 10 as a command line argument for size and sets it equal to buffSize which you recommended I put In my struct, I have the size already from command line arg and the array wont change. I would want to create an array of buff[buffSize];

Comment: @Aconcagua I just updated my code with your recommendations if you could take a look at it but i'm still stuck on where to initialize the buffer array as most people have it in their global variables and I'm not really sure how to set the buffer array in the struct to the buff size, like buff[buffSize] my attempt is on the new updated code.

Comment: @JosueNunez Well, forget about `realloc` then (see comments to answer – my fault, didn't read the entire code for being long – thus not aware of the command line arguments)! You could do: `int main(...) { shared_info shr; shr.numEntries = strtoul(...); /* note: I'd prefer unsigned as negative not meaningful anyway!*/ shr.buff = malloc(shr.numEntries * sizeof(*shr.buff)); /*...*/ pthread_create(..., &shr); /*...*/ }` Note that I decided rather to store how many *entries* you could store than how large the buffer is – that might be more helpful when using the buffer later on...

Comment: Within the struct `numEntries` – with recommendation above – should be of type `unsigned long` – or `long` if you remain with signed type – this is what `strto[u]l` actually returns – and [unsigned] int and long don't *necessarily* have the same size (e.g. on some micro-controllers `int` only has 16 bits, long 32; on 64-bit linux `long` has 64 bits while int only 32)!

Comment: Side note: I'd prefer always passing the end pointer to any of `strto[u][l]l` function family – this covers illegal input: `char* e; strtoul(argv[1], &e; 10); if(*e) { /* parsing error! */ }`

Comment: Just discovering undefined behaviour: With `shr->buff = malloc(buffSize * sizeof(int));` you are accessing the buffer out of range at `shr->buff[buffSize];`! What did you intend with???

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for your help but in the project that im working its asking for a more simple approach to this using simply buffersize...

Comment: And yet another one: `shared_info* shr; int main(...) { /*...*/ shr->in = 0; }` – you didn't ever assign anything to `shr` before reaching the assignment! Most likely your programme would crash due to a segmentation fault...

Comment: @Aconcagua Yea I know it was wrong but wasn't sure how to do it. shr->buff[buffSize]; I intended orginially to have an array in my struct like this buff[] to basically make a dynamically allocated array and once I got the size from the user command line argument I'd set the empty array and initialize it to the size of buffSize which contains the size of the array. Also I dont have shr-> in =0; in my code anymore i updated it like 30 minutes ago. If you refresh the page youll see my updated code

Comment: Sorry for confusion – your `bufferSize` already *is* in terms of number of ints – just noticing when seeing your call to malloc. Need to be more attendent – and indeed need to read full code… But *do* make it a member of `shared_info` struct to keep all relevant information together at a single place – and change the type to possibly unsigned `long` to correctly match the result of `strto[u]l`. Unsigned I'd prefer for negative sizes not being meaningful anyway, but leaving that to you...

Comment: @Aconcagua let me know once you see my updated code. Let me know if i'm on the right track

Comment: OK, didn't get the update – but you still have `shr` being a pointer, now locally – and you still don't assign anything to it. Remains undefined behaviour! Either `malloc` data for `shr` as well then or – preferably! – just drop the asterisk (so you create a struct directly within main) and convert all `shr->` within `main` (not in the thread routines!) to `shr.` – and call `pthread_create` with `&shr` then. See my comment where I draw a version of `main` myself.

Comment: `buffsize` still not changed either. If you assign the result of `strtol` to then it should have type `long` at very least. Or preferably `unsigned long` together with `strtoul` to reflect negative sizes being meaningless (-> self-documenting code).

Comment: `shr->buff[shr->buffSize];` still there, too. It does *not* do what the comment describes (this is what `malloc` does!) – instead it accesses the array out of bounds -> undefined behaviour. Brackets only specify an array size on array *declaration* (`int array[size];`) – anywhere else they are indexed array access. Note that `array[index]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(array + index)` – and as addition is commutable you can even commute the arguments of the index operator – `7[array]` is thus totally legal code identical to `array[7]`, the surprising and unusual it might be...

Comment: Yet another side note: `rand() % someMaximum` produces rather bad distributions; far better is `rand() * someMaximum / RAND_MAX` – though depending on the values of `someMaximum` and RAND_MAX you might need to keep an eye on overflow. The modulo is fine for just playing around, but keep the other variant in mind for more serious applications.

Comment: You can't change the size of an array, no matter what. `int arr[10];` defines an array with `10` elelements for as long as it's "alive". `int n; scanf("%d", &n); int arr[n]; /* assume everything ok*/` defines an array with `N` elements whatever that `N` is (if legal). Size never ever changes. What can change size is a space of memory where you point to with a *pointer*. `int *a = &argc;` defines a pointer that points to a place capable of holding `1` int .... `a = malloc(100 * sizeof *a); /* if all ok*/` now the pointer `a` points to a larger block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes.
First things first. Dynamic allocation, often requires you to use malloc, and thats fine. Thats literally the purpose of heap. And most often, if you allocate some memory you can get the size of allocated memory just by assigning the size to a variable before allocation.

```c
size_t size = some_number*sizeof(your_type);
//allocation using this variable
```

Or you can store number of elements of given type in this array(which is not the same as storing the size).

```c
your_type size = some_number;
//allocation using this variable*sizeof(your_type)
```

So just add this variable to your struct, or store it independently.
Dynamic allocation is a very convinent tool, and you should use it to make your life easier(or harder, if you let it leak later).

Second. You use semaphores. You should always think for a second if what you want to use is in reality a mutex itself, not a generalization. Basically, if you want to be sure that only one thread is allowed in a critical section no matter what, you should always use mutex.

Third. You use semaphores for conditional signaling. Use conditional variable instead.

Fourth. Dont make shr a global variable. Its a very bad practise. You can pass it as an argument to the thread, and then cast it back.
Void* is compatible with every pointer, so you can pass whatever pointer you want.
pthread as is written in documentation:

```c
The pthread_create() function starts a new thread in the calling
       process.  The new thread starts execution by invoking
       start_routine(); arg is passed as the sole argument of
       start_routine().
```

You correctly defined thread function, but you didnt use arg* at all.
You should do:

```c
pthread_create(&pro, NULL, producer, &shr);
```

and then in producer/consumer:

```c
void *producer(void * arg){
   shared_info *shr = *(shared_info**)arg;
   //producer routine
}
```

And put it back in main function. Dont make it global.

Lastly. If you allocate memory, no matter whats the scope youre in, you can access this memory from anywhere within your program, just by providing the adress returned by function you used to allocate this memory. Note that its a case just for your program, you cannot do it like that between diffrent processes(to put it simply: programs).

Comment: why would I have to put  shared_info *shr = *(shared_info**)arg; Wouldn't I be able to just do   sem_wait(&arg->empty); Does arg still change the memory in shr or is arg only changing memory in the producer function? I want it to change for every thrread

Comment: shared_info shr = *(shared_info**)arg. Its a pointer to pointer, which you dereference. From what i know, you should pass address of a pointer if you want to pass it to thread function(to be honest i dont know why).
Arg doesnt change anything in memory. Its just a pointer. shr and arg, points to the same place in memory, which is your struct so it doesnt change anything in your struct. sem_wait() is very different from conditional variable waiting.

Comment: @JosueNunez That's questionable a bit... If `shr` *is* a pointer already you'd rather pass it directly to `pthread_create` as the `void*` argument (`shr` instead of `&shr`) – provided you wouldn't want to modify the original pointer itself from within the other thread. Then getting back is just too simple (not even requiring a cast): `shared_info* shr = arg;`. And if you make `shr` a local variable within main (`shared_info shr;` – note: no pointer!) then you'd make an ordinary pointer from by (then yes, `&shr`) – but assignment within the thread remains `shared_info* shr = arg;`.

Comment: Yeah i edited my comment to explain. Its just that someone higher up told me to do it that way, and i didnt ask why.

Comment: @RychuKropkaExe There's no such double pointer requirement mentioned within [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) – and never heard of elsewhere either…

Comment: *'or store it independently'* – I'd drop that recommendation – the size is just too closely related to the buffer to be stored outside the struct (sole exception: struct coming from external resource and is thus not safely modifiable, but doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: I'm also supposed to use semaphores not conditional signaling

Comment: While avoiding global variables in general *is* a good idea just keep in mind that it sometimes can get impractical up to impossible – consider e.g. signal handlers or interrupt service routines where there simply are no parameters available to be passed to (apart from the signal/interrupt id in some implementations)…

Comment: @Aconcagua Im super confused to be honest, would you be able to show me how it would look making that change in my code specifically my struct to show how to pass the size so that all thread can add data into the buffer array? Also when you say I should pass it as shr instead of &shr thats confusing because I do pass it as shr in my pthread_create.

Comment: @JosueNunez `shared_info *shr;` -> `pthread_create(..., shr);` is totally fine – answer, in contrast, takes the address of the pointer which is *not* necessary. On the other hand, if you convert `shr` into a local variable (as recommended in question), *then* you'd need it: `int main() { shared_info shr; /* note: no pointer any more! */ pthread_create(..., &shr); ... }`. In either case: `void* threadHandler(void* arg) { shared_info* shr = arg; ... }`.